# оптимизация работы с libpcap на c

Tags: c, tcp, libpcap

Используется библиотека для снифинга пакетов libpcap в debian 8. Машина старенькая 2 гб озу, Intel core 2 duo T6600 2200 MHz. Есть опасения, что поток данных порядка более 100 мегабит затормозит систему или же часть пакетов будет упущена(данная информация о пропуске пакетов из источников 2009 года, и вроде как данный баг был исправлен. Всё же хочется услышать мнение тех, кто с ней работал) в том случае, если в функции библиотеки

```
pcap_loop(..., -1, callback, ...); //протокол только http
```

моя функция callback будет занимать слишком много времени. Функция выполняет обработку пакетов на лету, выборку и склеивание нескольких tcp пакетов в единый файл(полноценный html, например) после этого сохранение данного файла на диск и т.д.

В случае, если появятся тормоза, то как лучше организовать архитектуру приложения? Может создать временный буфер накапливать N пакетов, а после скидывать дамп на диск  или держать его в памяти, затем данные парсить в отдельном процессе(потоке)? Но в таком случае придется использовать синхронизацию, что я боюсь тоже скажется на производительности. В кратце - есть прокси сервер, необходимо слушать конкретный интерфейс и вести учёт запросов пользователей сети, подключенных к этому прокси вместе с их данными.

Comment: Прокси работает на уровне пользователя. Вы хотите трафик идущий сеть-ядро-прокси вытаскивать на этой же машине еще раз в юзерспейс отдельно от прокси. Это не рационально. Гораздо проще модифицировать код прокси сервера. Тем более что там протокол прикладного уровня доступен сразу и не надо вообще делать обработку ip/tcp заголовков

Comment: @Mike я с вами согласен. Изначально (очень давно) tcpdump слушал интерфейс и сбрасывал дампы на диск, после проходил их анализ. tcpdump как раз использует libpcap, в связи с этим и появилось желание написать скажем так свой tcpdump. К сожалению изменить код прокси сервера возможности так же нет. Вы конечно натолкнули на мысль взять какой-нибудь open-source и так же заточить под свой нужды, но боюсь с этим могут возникнуть некоторые проблемы(не в плане написания кода). Вот впрос и встал как быть...